# Proper procedure - sftp access to www folder - To be able to upload files

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, sftp, nginx

My www folder is root:root. What should it be? My site works perfectly but maybe I am doing something wrong.

My nginx.conf says user is 'nginx'. Should I be changing the www onwership and group to that or something else?

Mainly I want to be able to sftp into the www folder using FileZilla. Preferably only allow access to the www folder. I want to be able to upload the website files but I just don't know the proper procedure.

I have tried changing owners and groups but I get worried some part of the stack will not like it. For example does nginx play along, and php?

I thought about having a sftp group or even an sftp user. But I don't want to go down a path that should be avoided.

What should I be doing with my setup?

**Edit:**

I should have been more clear. It is CentOS running on a VPS.

My question about the SFTP relates to the permissions - I wanted to login through FileZilla and drag over a few html files into the web directory of one of the sites.

But of course I don't have the proper permissions and I wanted to know what is the best way to approach permissions - A learning exercise mostly.

I want it to be secure and for example might only want the sftp user to be able to see one particular web directory. But I am new to a lot of linux and the permissions, owners and groups are a challenge.

Comment: can you be a little more clear? What should I be doing with my setup is rather vague. We can definately help with specific questions, but this isnt a plain answer, this is a whole situation

Comment: I would really just like to know what others do with their permissions. From research I can see a lot recommend having a group that has permissions to read, write etc and then add users to that group as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have OpenSSH installed and running.
`chkconfig sshd on`

Start the service manually, or check status
`/etc/init.d/sshd status`
`/etc/init.d/sshd start`

Edit: **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**
Make sure this is included;

```
...
    Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
...
```

Add the following lines for each user|group you would like to include

```
Match User fooba
    ChrootDirectory /home
    AllowTCPForwarding no  
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Be sure to set the following directives;

```
PermitRootLogin no  
AllowUsers fooba
```

Now restart ssh;
`/etc/init.d/ssh restart`

As for user access controls and directory permissions, I suggest reading this [post](http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/) if you are not already familiar.

And **finally**, this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/392601/how-to-add-user-with-sftp-ftp-access-to-var-www-html-website-abc-folder-on-a) which does a really good job explaining a more specific scenario like yours.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have been more clear. It is CentOS running on a VPS. My question about the SFTP relates to the permissions - I wanted to login through FileZilla and drag over a few html files into the web directory of one of the sites. But of course I don't have the proper permissions and I wanted to know what is the best way to approach permissions - A learning exercise mostly. I want it to be secure and for example might only want the sftp user to be able to see one particular web directory. But I am new to a lot of linux and the permissions, owners and groups are a challenge.

Comment: edit this into your main question @Jay